# Handcent profile picture for texting

Tags: handcent-sms

Device: Samsung Galaxy S2

How do I set my contact picture for text messaging, so everyone sees what I have set as my profile pic on Handcent?

Answer (score 0):

Like most SMS, Contacts, or Dialer apps, the contact photos either come from:

- Facebook
- Google
- *Other apps*
- Manually set by User (owner of phone)

In the last case, only YOU can see it. It's not possible to share / broadcast this image since it is your photo that you added to your own local contact.

For Facebook contacts or Google contacts, the photos come from the profile picture of your social media account. This is what is visible to other users, **ONLY IF** they have shown Facebook / Google contacts, instead of just phone contacts. Otherwise, they still won't see your photo.